# Calculated column in view performance issue

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework, sql-server-2016

I've got a table with location data (Lat/Lngs) stored as geography type.

Now this location data represents a Journey, so I want to calculate the distance travelled during the Journey, distance per day and distance per month. So for this I need a property to calculate the distance from the next location in the Journey.

If I do this using a Select from the table with a Window Function, the performance is very good and the Execution Plan seems fine. [Execution Plan](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=S1aj7eCLX)

This is the Query -

```
Select
    iVehicleMonitoringId,
    iAssetId,
    iDriverId,
    dtUtcDatetime,
    sptGeoLocaitonPoint,
    fAngel,
    sDirection,
    fSpeedKPH,
    eEventCode,
    fDistanceTravelled = sptGeoLocaitonPoint.STDistance(LEAD(sptGeoLocaitonPoint) OVER(PARTITION BY iAssetId ORDER BY dtUTCDateTime)),
    eIgnition,
    eDoor,
    eSeatbelt,
    eIgnition2,
    sAddress
From dbo.VehicleMonitoringLog

Where iAssetId = 1
    AND dtUTCDateTime BETWEEN N'2017-12-27' AND N'2017-12-27 23:59:59.997'
```

Now because I need this Distance Calculated property in my code. I decided to create an SQL View with the `fDistanceTravelled` property.

```
CREATE VIEW [dbo].[TB5_xPT_VehicleMonitoringLogs]
AS
    Select
        iVehicleMonitoringId = ISNULL(iVehicleMonitoringId, -1),
        iAssetId,
        iDriverId,
        dtUtcDatetime,
        sptGeoLocaitonPoint,
        fAngel,
        sDirection,
        fSpeedKPH,
        eEventCode,
        fDistanceTravelled = sptGeoLocaitonPoint.STDistance(LEAD(sptGeoLocaitonPoint) OVER(PARTITION BY iAssetId ORDER BY dtUTCDateTime)),
        eIgnition,
        eDoor,
        eSeatbelt,
        eIgnition2,
        sAddress
    From dbo.VehicleMonitoringLog
GO
```

But when I import this View into my Entity Framework, it gets a timeout. So I checked the Execution Plan and it doesn't match that of selecting from the Table.
[View Execution Plan](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=BJQOmgCIm)

This is the query -

```
Select
    *
From TB5_xPT_VehicleMonitoringLogs
Where iAssetId = 1
    AND dtUTCDateTime BETWEEN N'2017-12-27' AND N'2017-12-27 23:59:59.997'
```

To do this in code I need to loop through all the location logs in the list.

```
DbGeography prevPoint = null;
foreach (var historyLog in historyLogs)
{
    var distanceFromPrevPoint = 0.0;
    if (prevPoint != null)
    {
        var distance = prevPoint.Distance(historyLog.sptGeoLocaitonPoint);
        if (distance != null)
            distanceFromPrevPoint = Math.Round(((double)distance * .001), 2);
    }

    var locationLog = Mapper.Map<LocationLogDTO>(historyLog);

    locationLog.DistanceTravelled = distanceFromPrevPoint;

    prevPoint = historyLog.sptGeoLocaitonPoint;

    historyDto.LocationLogs.Add(locationLog);
}
```

I don't want to do this. I need a better way of doing this.

**EDIT**

Image Explaining the `fDistanceTravelled` column calculation.

[image]

Comment: instead of showing the logic in code. can you explain it a bit? Like a sample input + output + explanation on what the logic behind it is?

Comment: Each row in the table is a location log in a Journey I need to calculate the distance between them and return it in the result-set. The input is a list of location logs without the fDistanceTravelled column - The output should have the fDistanceTravelled column (where the fDistanceTravelled is the distance from next position in the Location Logs Table)

Comment: @Steve I've added an image explaining the logic for fDistanceTravelled

Comment: How are you mapping the view results in EF? Are these mapped as an independent entity, or are you extending HistoryLog? Is the fDistanceTravelled mapped as DatabaseGeneratedOption.Computed?